# what does it mean to get a Rasters DataBuffer

Tags: java, image, rendering, pixel, raster

I've been trying to practice some active rendering involving triple buffering and manipulating a BufferedImage's raster. however, as I was watching some videos and reading articles, I noticed programers using this method invocation hierarchy to get the raster's pixels
`((DataBufferInt) BufferedImage.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData()` I know what does the method getRaster() return, but I'm confused about the other ones especially the `getDataBuffer()`. can somebody please explain what is a data buffer exactly, and what  is happening when invoking those methods?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's an abstraction for the low level storage of the data being rendered. In your example, the data is stored in the buffer as an int array, but it could also be a byte, float, double, etc.